# Apache Beam and Hive complex types

Tags: hive, apache-beam, hive-serde

I have an hive table with a column of type `map<string,string` which I would like to feed into a Beam pipeline. I am doing the following

```
HCatalogIO.Read hiveIo = HCatalogIO.read()
      .withConfigProperties(configProperties)
      .withDatabase("db") 
      .withTable("web_search_log")
      .withFilter("yyyy_mm_dd == '2019-09-01'");
p.apply(HCatToRow.fromSpec(hiveIo))
```

but I discovered complex types are not supported

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The type 'map<string,string>' of field 'price_buckets' is not supported.
at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.hcatalog.HCatalogBeamSchema.getTableSchema(HCatalogBeamSchema.java:88)
```

How can I read this table? It would also be fine skipping the complex types and get only the ones that are supported

Comment: It looks like we need a change to do projection pushdown to HCatalogIO to be able to skip the Map column, and unfortunately such pushdown might not exist, neither.

Comment: Note that BeamSQL does support MAP type, but the problem is reading the MAP type through HCatalog IO.

Comment: Hi Rui, Can you please provide any up to date sample code to read from Hive and save it as Row format from Pcollection? (I checked Apache beam website example but for some reason it is not working)